# How to reconnect partitioned nodes in erlang cluster

Tags: erlang, cluster-computing, distributed-system

Looking for some solutions to handle Erlang cluster partitions. Basically, whenever cluster participant is reachable again it should be added back to the cluster.The easiest solution is probably to use [erlang node monitoring](http://erlang.org/doc/man/net_kernel.html#monitor_nodes-2).

Are there any other / better solutions, maybe more dynamic which does not require fixed nodes list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few 3rd party libraries that don't have to be configured using a fixed node list. The two that I am familiar with are [redgrid](https://github.com/JacobVorreuter/redgrid) and [erlang-redis_sd_epmd](https://github.com/redis-sd/erlang-redis_sd_epmd), there are probably others, but i'm just not familiar with them.

Both of these do have an external dependancy on [redis](http://redis.io) which may or may not be desirable depending on what you decide is needed.

**redgrid** is the simpler implementation, but doesn't have a ton of features. Basically the erlang nodes connect to redis, and all erlang nodes connected to redis then establish connections to each other. You can associate meta-data with a node and retrieve it on another node.

**erlang-redis_sd_epmd** is a bit more complex, but allows a lot more configuration. For example instead of just automatically connecting all nodes, a node can publish services that it can perform, and a connecting node can look up nodes based on the services provided.

Answer (score 1):

Not an off the shelf solution, but if you're already doing custom mods to ejabberd you can try integrating this code which resolves mnesia conflicts after cluster partitions.

https://github.com/uwiger/unsplit